# Polars search_sorted window function

Tags: python-polars

Is it possible to use a window function with `search_sorted`?

So given this example:

```py
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({
    'left_on': ['b', 'b', 'd', 'd'],
})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({
    'right_on': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
})

(
    df1
    .lazy()
    .with_context(df2.lazy())
    .with_columns([
        pl.col('right_on').search_sorted(pl.col('left_on'), side='left')
    ])
    .collect()
)
"""
┌─────────┬──────────┐
│ left_on ┆ right_on │
│ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ str     ┆ u32      │
╞═════════╪══════════╡
│ b       ┆ 1        │
│ b       ┆ 1        │
│ d       ┆ 3        │
│ d       ┆ 3        │
└─────────┴──────────┘
"""
```

Are we able to achieve windowing functionality like this?

```py
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({
    'left_on': ['b', 'b', 'd', 'd'] * 2,
    'by_left': ['X'] * 4 + ['Y'] * 4,
})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({
    'right_on': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] * 2,
    'by_right': ['X'] * 5 + ['Y'] * 5,
})

(
    df1
    .lazy()
    .with_context(df2.lazy())
    .with_columns([
        pl.col('right_on').search_sorted(pl.col('left_on'), side='left', by_left='by_left', by_right='by_right')
    ])
    .collect()
)
"""
┌─────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ left_on ┆ by_left ┆ right_on │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ u32      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ b       ┆ X       ┆ 1        │
│ b       ┆ X       ┆ 1        │
│ d       ┆ X       ┆ 3        │
│ d       ┆ X       ┆ 3        │
│ b       ┆ Y       ┆ 6        │
│ b       ┆ Y       ┆ 6        │
│ d       ┆ Y       ┆ 8        │
│ d       ┆ Y       ┆ 8        │
└─────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
"""
```

I understand something similar can be achieved using `join_asof`, but `search_sorted` has the additional benefit of being able to specify the side (`any`, `left`, `right`). It can also "search" on UTF-8, which `join_asof` is unable to.

The following also appears to be a valid `expr` but it doesn't seem to give meaningful results.

```
pl.col('right_on').search_sorted(pl.col('left_on'), side='left').over('by_left')
```

Comment: I think the "non-meaningful results" are because the data ends up "not sorted". `by_left` has a length of `4`, so you end up with `['e', 'a', 'b', 'c']` for `by_left='Y'` - does `pl.col('right_on').sort().search_sorted()` gives the result you expect?

Comment: @jqurious It still doesn't make sense to me. `search_sorted` gives you the index of of an element in `left_on` if inserted into `right_on`. This index shouldn't change when a window is introduced in `left_on`.

Comment: But the `.over` is essentially the same as: `df.groupby('by_left', maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('right_on').search_sorted(pl.col('left_on'), side='left'))` so it's searching `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` for 'X' and `['e', 'a', 'b', 'c']` for 'Y'?

Comment: @jqurious I see, that explains the results, thanks! Though in that case I don't think that will work for this question, since I'm essentially asking if `search_sorted` can be done on the entire `right_on` (by group).

Comment: `pl.concat([df1.with_row_count(), df2.with_row_count()], how='align')` may help visualize it, it's grouping rows `0-3` together and `4-7`. It sounds more like a filter/join type thing rather than a grouping as the entire `right_on` is not sorted, and the "groups" are different sizes. Maybe it would help if you explained why you want `[1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8]` What would you do with this result? Is there a next step/end goal? Perhaps there's an alternative approach.